# iOS: Sqlite database error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'error preparing statement'

Tags: iphone, ios, error-handling, sqlite, compiler-errors

I had used sqlite DB for my application and i need to call the two simultaneous queries, but i giving error as : **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'error preparing statement'**

I am running a timer of every 10 seconds for **Selecting rows from DB** and **Insert rows in DB** after a button event.

My code snippet as:

in `viewWillAppear`:

```
int result2 = sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database);
if (result2 != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"Failure in connecting to the database with result %d",result2);
}
else {
    NSLog(@ "Succesfully opened connection to DB") ;

}
```

and in `viewWillDisappear`:

```
int result = sqlite3_close(database);
if (result != SQLITE_OK){
    NSLog(@"Failure in closing connection to database. Result %d",result);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Successfully closed DB connection") ;
}
```

For `Inserting rows`:

```
NSString *queryInsert = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"insert into mail_snoozlist (msgBody,msgSubject, msgSender,msgTo,msgDate,snoozTime) values('%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@')",strBody,msgSub,msgFrom,msgTo,strMsgDate,stringFromDate];

    NSLog(@"queryInsert:%@",queryInsert);

    const char *sql = [queryInsert UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_step(statement);
        sqlite3_reset(statement);

    } else {

        NSAssert1(0,@"error preparing statement",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        return;
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

and for `Selecting rows`:

```
NSString *querySQL2 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Select * from mail_snoozlist WHERE snoozTime = '%@'",_snoozTime];

    NSLog(@"querySql:%@",querySQL2);

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [querySQL2 UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            Message *obj = [[Message alloc] init];

            NSString *msgBody=[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            obj.msgBody= msgBody;

            NSString *msgSub=[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
            obj.msgSub= msgSub;

            NSString *msgSender=[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
            obj.msgFrom= msgSender;

            NSString *msgTo=[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];
            obj.msgTo= msgTo;

            NSString *msgDate=[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5)];
            obj.msgDate= msgDate;

            [listOfItems addObject:obj];

            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }

        sqlite3_reset(statement);
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

Anyone please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should change your `NSAssert` statement to include the error message:

```
NSAssert1(0, @"error preparing statement: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
```

Once you do that, you should get a meaningful response which will help you diagnose the problem.

Without looking at the `sqlite3_errmsg` message, it is difficult to diagnose the problem. It could be as simple as a typo in a column name or table name or as complicated as the table not being found because the database wasn't found when it was created, so a blank database (without that table) was created. Hard to say until we see the error message.

---

As an aside, you should not be building your SQL with `stringWithFormat` because you open yourself to SQL injection attacks as well as will have problems if any of those text values have an apostrophe in them. You should use `?` placeholders instead of printf-style formatters, and then bind the values to those columns with `sqlite3_bind_text` calls:

```
NSString *queryInsert = @"insert into mail_snoozlist (msgBody,msgSubject, msgSender,msgTo,msgDate,snoozTime) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSAssert1(0,@"error preparing statement: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    return;
}

// for these 6 sqlite3_bind function calls, if any of these strings can be `nil`, then you'd
// want to call sqlite3_bind_null if that's the case, rather than sqlite3_bind_text

if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [strBody UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSAssert1(0,@"error binding 1: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    return;
}

if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [msgSub UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSAssert1(0,@"error binding 2: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    return;
}

if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [msgFrom UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSAssert1(0,@"error binding 3: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    return;
}

if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [msgTo UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSAssert1(0,@"error binding 4: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    return;
}

if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 5, [strMsgDate UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSAssert1(0,@"error binding 5: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    return;
}

if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 6, [stringFromDate UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSAssert1(0,@"error binding 6: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    return;
}

if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
    NSAssert1(0,@"error stepping: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

I illustrate the issue with the `insert` statement, but the same should be done with the `select` statement, too.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I had solve this issue by a bit change in query:

`NSString *queryInsert = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"insert into mail_snoozlist (msgBody,msgSubject, msgSender,msgTo,msgDate,snoozTime) values('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",[strBody UTF8String] ,[msgObj.msgSub UTF8String] ,[msgObj.msgFrom UTF8String],[msgObj.msgTo UTF8String],[strMsgDate UTF8String],[stringFromDate UTF8String]];`

Comment: @Pankaj First, you still should add the `%s` to your `NSAssert1` line otherwise you'll never see the `sqlite3_errmsg` when you get errors. Second, changing the `%@` to `%s` in your SQL only coincidentally works, actually doesn't remedy any problem, and only makes the code less legible. Third, if your proposed change tries to insert a `strBody` or a `msgSubject` that happens to have an apostrophe in it, and your code will still crash. Do not use `stringWithFormat` to build SQL, but rather use `sqlite3_bind_text`. Plus, a devious user could do a SQL injection attack, e.g. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: I add this code, but now i am getting the error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'error preparing statement: library routine called out of sequence'`. And i didn't get any **error binding log**.

Comment: @Pankaj Now your assert reports the precise SQLite error message: Excellent. This error, "library routine called out of sequence", tells you you haven't followed the [prescribed order of calls](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html). This can happen if you closed the database and neglected to reopen it, for example. I don't think the error is in this code, above, but elsewhere. Step through your code, checking the order that you call open, prepare, bind, step, finalize, and close. In particular, put a breakpoint/log at the `sqlite3_open` and `sqlite3_close` lines.

Comment: @Pankaj See [the documentation on your error](http://sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=LibraryRoutineCalledOutOfSequence).

Answer (score 0):

Add these two methods and call them in insert method before insertion and selection,

```
 - (void) createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded
{


    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbname.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (success) return;
    //{

    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbname.sqlite"];

    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
    // }
    if (!success)
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}


- (void)initializeDatabase
 {



NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbname.sqlite"];
sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database);
}
```

Comment: for calling use these lines// [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
    [self initializeDatabase];

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I had solve this issue by a bit change in query:

`NSString *queryInsert = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"insert into mail_snoozlist (msgBody,msgSubject, msgSender,msgTo,msgDate,snoozTime) values('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')",[strBody UTF8String] ,[msgObj.msgSub UTF8String] ,[msgObj.msgFrom UTF8String],[msgObj.msgTo UTF8String],[strMsgDate UTF8String],[stringFromDate UTF8String]];`